# Generic Methods Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

Is there any difference between these 2 generic methods?

1. `public static <E> void fill(ArrayList<? extends Comparable<? super E>> a)`
2. `public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void fill2(ArrayList<E> a)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the binding of `E` is different. Given some

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>
```

and some

```
class Bar implements Comparable<Foo> // Not Bar!
```

`Foo` would be a legal argument to both `fill` and `fill2` as the second method requires `E = Foo` to both extend `Comparable` and to have this `Comparable` implementation to be of `E = Foo`. This cannot be fulfilled by `Bar`.